# How to create a maintenance mode page in cakephp?

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, maintenance-mode

I am new to cakephp framework. what is the procedure to create a under construction or maintenance page in an existing site as am going to do some changes. am using cakephp 1.3. 
I googled it but it didnt get any step by step process.

I referred the Links below :

http://mark-story.com/posts/view/quick-and-dirty-down-for-maintenance-page-with-cakephp
http://www.fedevel.com/welldoneblog/2011/01/cakephp-quick-and-simple-maintenance-page/

can anybody give me a solution .

Comment: What is wrong with the solutions in those links? What exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following code to your index.php file in public or webroot folder :

`define('MAINTENANCE', 0); 
if(MAINTENANCE > 0 && $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] !='188.YOUR.IP.HERE'){
require('maintenance.php'); die(); 
}`

In order to enable the mode you have to change the `0` to `1` in the first line of the code.

Place your IP in the place `188.YOUR.IP.HERE` from where you will make changes.

Also add `maintenance.php` file in the same folder where the index.php that you have edited. `maintenance.php` file is the maintenance mode template file.